# How can I check I am actually connected to the internet

Tags: ftp, indy, delphi-xe

I am using Indy to connect to an Ftp server.  We have had problems with the server being down, creating a "Host not found" error, which I handle and indicate to the user, however, today the software was installed on a computer that did not have an internet connection.  The error produced when I "Connect" is also "Host not found", which is not totally correct.  Is there a function/procedure I can call inside the TIdFtp component that will tell me if there is actually a connection to the internet so I can display an error indicating the user is not connected?  I am using Delphi XE Seattle.

I have looked through the list of IdFtp properties/functions etc, but nothing seems obvious.

Comment: Difficult to define what it means to be connected to the Internet. Host not found sounds like an accurate response to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function/procedure I can call inside the TIdFtp component that will tell me if there is actually a connection to the internet so I can display an error indicating the user is not connected?

No. What you will have to do is attempt a TCP connection to several different servers and see if any of them succeed or if they all fail. For instance, you can use `TIdTCPClient` to connect to well-known server ports that are pretty much guaranteed to be online 99+% of the time, like `google.com`/`yahoo.com` on port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS), etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for your usual prompt answers!  I knew when I posted that there would be two people who would almost certainly offer suggestions/solutions, you are both a walking reference library!  At the weekend I searched further and created this function found in WinInet: 
var
   origin : cardinal;
begin
   result := InternetGetConnectedState(@origin,0);
end;
I had thought of connecting to other sites, but this should do, most likely the error means the user has not connected their laptop to a internet provider.

Comment: @TrevorH there are many different ways to be connected to the internet, and WinInet doesn't really know or care about them, only that there is a network connection. But having a network connection does not guarantee an internet connection. Functions like `InternetGetConnectionState()` are notoriously unreliable. Actually connecting to a server on the Internet is the simplest and best approach.

Comment: I might extend my function based on your comment.  Maybe do an initial test, and then attempt to connect to a couple of sites that are almost always up!  If both of these fail, I can tell the user to check their connection, they have most likely forgotten to plug something in or connect to a mobile phone or WiFi network.