# AV after TIdHttp.get from an https site

Tags: http, indy, delphi-xe

After checking for an HTTPS site, I get no errors and can return that the Internet connection seems to be working, however when I close the program I get an AV.

This is a followup to my previous post about checking an Internet connection is working.

I have modified my function, as suggested, and now check a couple of sites, however, if I access an HTTPS site, my function works, but when I close the program I get an AV. If I have only accessed HTTP sites for the test, no AV occurs on close.

This is a snippit of the function, the first site I access is HTTPS, so I don't need a handler, which makes it simpler. If I comment out the HTTPS and uncomment HTTP it works, no AV. The actual function tests several sites, but this creates the error easily.

Do I need to do something extra when accessing HTTPS sites?

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnTestConnectionClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  http: TIdHttp; 
  bFound: boolean;
begin 
  bFound := True; 
  http := TIdHttp.Create(nil); 
  try 
    try 
      //http.Get('http://www.google.com'); 
      http.Get('https://www.wikipedia.org'); 
    except 
      bFound := False; 
    end; 
  finally 
    FreeAndNil(http); 
  end; 
  if not bFound then 
    ShowMessage('Internet not working')
  else 
    ShowMessage('Internet working'); 
end;
```

The return value is as expected, it works if I try several sites until one is found (indicating the Internet is working) but if I access an HTTPS site, I get the AV when the program closes.

Comment: Your code is fine, the AV is likely related to something else. You need to debug your code and track down the root cause. However, that said, you don't need to deal with HTTPS at all just to test for a valid connection. In fact, you don't even need to use TIdHTTP at all, using TIdTCPClient by itself will suffice. All you need is to connect to a given port on a few servers, you don't need to actually communicate with them. I told you as much in my previous answer

Comment: What is the point of checking whether or not you can connect to google.com if your real goal is to connect to something else? Since you need to handle errors in your really communication code, why waste time checking whether you can connect to some other site?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, the AV is likely related to something else. You need to debug your code and track down the root cause.

However, that said, you don't need to deal with HTTPS at all just to test for a valid connection. In fact, you don't even need to use `TIdHTTP` at all, using `TIdTCPClient` by itself will suffice. All you need is to connect to a given port on a few servers, you don't need to actually communicate with them (I told you as much in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57214402/65863) to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213954/)), eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnTestConnectionClick(Sender: TObject); 
const
  Hosts: array[0..1] of string = ('www.google.com', 'www.wikipedia.org'{, ...});
var 
  tcp: TIdTCPClient; 
  host: string;
  bFound: boolean;
begin 
  bFound := False;
  try
    tcp := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil); 
    try 
      for host in Hosts do
      begin
        tcp.Host := host;
        tcp.Port := 80; // or 443...
        try
          tcp.Connect;
        except
          Continue;
        end;
        tcp.Disconnect;
        bFound := True;
        Break;
      end;
    finally 
      tcp.Free; 
    end; 
  except
  end;
  if not bFound then 
    ShowMessage('Internet not working')
  else 
    ShowMessage('Internet working'); 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Remy, much appreciated.  I guess I was focused on getting past the AV when connecting to https, rather than looking outside the box.